# Should a server adhere to the HTTP Connection: close header sent from a client?

Tags: http, rest, header, connection

I have a HTTP client that sets the Connection header to the following value when I make a request:

```
   Connection: close
```

However when the server sends a response, it is setting the header to Keep-Alive:

```
   Connection: Keep-Alive
```

This seems intuitively wrong to me, and I am wondering how the client should handle such a response from the server?  Also why would a server respond with Keep-Alive, when the client has asked for the connection to be closed, is this valid?

According to the HTTP RFC:

"HTTP/1.1 defines the "close" connection option for the sender to signal that the connection will be closed after completion of the response. For example,

```
   Connection: close
```

in either the request or the response header fields indicates that the connection SHOULD NOT be considered `persistent' (section 8.1) after the current request/response is complete."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's fine.  You are telling the server you don't support persistent connections and it's telling you it does.  Either party is completely valid in closing the connection - it's more of a message about what both supports rather then a YOU MUST CLOSE THIS CONNECTION command.

Answer (score 6):

The client says *I* will close the connection when the current request/response is finished,or in other words , said you don't support persisten connections. That is, it  doesn't tell the server to close the connection. The server replies that it supports persistent connections(keep-alive).

As you've told the server that you don't support persistent connection, you should close the connection when you've read the response.