# Http keep-alive protocol "Connection: close" from client but no "connection" header from server

Tags: java, http, odata, keep-alive, sap-erp

I've a problem with broken connections and I believe this is due to an incorrect behavior respect to http keepalive but I can't understand if the 'culpit' is on the client or on the server side.

I'm dealing with a scenario where the client sends and HTTP 1.1 request with:

```
Connection: close
```

and the server does NOT reply with a Connection header.
The behavior is as follows:

1. The client sends the request
2. The server sends it response
3. The server does NOT close the connection
4. The client does NOT close the connection (.1)
5. The client sends another request using the same connection
6. The server does not do anything and after 30" closes the connection

The components are as follows:

- Client: Java HttpConnection (within Dell Boomi iPaaS)
- Server: SAP ERP OData Webservice

According to this article: "[Should a server adhere to the HTTP Connection: close header sent from a client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424796/should-a-server-adhere-to-the-http-connection-close-header-sent-from-a-client)" the problem seems to be on the client side. However the Java HttpURLCoonnection implementation should be pretty robust (tested x64 server VM on Linux v 1.7.0_55-b13 and x64 server on Windows 7 v 1.7.0_75-b13).

Here are the complete set of headers from the 1st request from client:

```
GET /sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZZSALESORDER_SRV/$metadata HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Boomi Http Transport
Authorization: Basic YmPRIVATESECRETPLEASExNg==
X-CSRF-Token: Fetch
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Host: some.server.behind.firewall.local:8000
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Cookie: sap-usercontext=sap-client=100; SAP_SESSIONID_DEV_100=Cm7LsDSECRETSECRETSECTERFaIMak%3d
```

And these are the ones from the response from the server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: application/xml
content-length: 79750
x-csrf-token: oolTHISAGAINISASECRET3PA==
last-modified: Fri, 25 Mar 2016 17:55:35 GMT
dataserviceversion: 2.0
```

After the server has replied the client sends a second request using the same connection:

```
PUT /sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZZSALESORDER_SRV/SalesOrderItems(NumDocSap='1200001534',PosId='000020') HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Boomi Http Transport
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
X-CSRF-Token: oolZMYSECRETPA==
Connection: close
Authorization: Basic YmPRIVATESECRETPLEASExNg==
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Host: some.server.behind.firewall.local:8000
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Content-Length: 406
Cookie: sap-usercontext=sap-client=100; SAP_SESSIONID_DEV_100=Cm7PRETTYPRIVATESECRETak%3d
```

and the server does not reply and closed the connection abruptly after 30".

The problem can be completely resolved setting the JVM flag

```
http.keepAlive=false
```

on the java client side (Boomi) but this seems more of a workaround then a solution.

Can someone please explain:

- is there an HTTP protocol violation on client or server side?
- can this be fixed by sending different headers?